# App crashes before presenting view controller second time iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, presentviewcontroller

I'm developing an app which works with a specific SDK. To present its ViewController, I call the method getViewController provided by the SDK.

If I try to present it the first time everything works perfectly, using this call:

```
self.presentViewController(XCASDK_Manager.sharedManager().getXCAViewController(), animated: true, completion: {()->Void in })
```

When I dismiss it, I call this method:

```
[[[XCASDK_Manager sharedManager] getXCAViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^(){ });
```

Now there's the problem: when I try to present a second time the SDK's viewController, using the same method, the app crashes with LLDB error.

I tried it in iOS 7 and there's no problem, so I can say that the problem is linked to iOS 8.

Does anyone have the solution about this problem?

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: 'lldb' is the debugger. Debugger console has no crash logs?

Comment: The only things that I show are: LLDB in my debugger console, and a breakpoint with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address...) which points to AppDelegate